# get step function execution result

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3, aws-step-functions

I'm new to AWS and struggling with step function.

My workflow is like this:

client ('search_word')-> api gateway -> lambda function (invoke step function) -> step function (generate search output) -> client

Here's my invoke lambda function.

```
import json
import boto3
import uuid

client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    transactionId = str(uuid.uuid1())
    print(transactionId) 
    
    input = {'TransactionId':transactionId,'text':'search_word'} 
    
    response = client.start_execution(
        stateMachineArn='arn:aws:states:ap-northeast-2:xxxxxxxxxx:stateMachine:MyStateMachine',
        name=transactionId,
        input=json.dumps(input)
        )
        
    print(response) 
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I want to get the execution result from step function and pass it to client. But I have no idea how to do it.

The workflow doesn't have to be what I suggested as long as I can give the execution result of step function to the client.

Here's my step function.

```
{ 
  "Comment": "A simple AWS Step Functions state machine.", 
  "StartAt": "Tokenize", 
  "States": {  
    "Tokenize": { 
      "Type": "Task", 
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-2:xxxxxxxx:function:search_ko", 
      "Next": "Search"
    }, 
    "Search": { 
      "Type": "Task", 
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-2:xxxxxxx:function:BM-25-Get-Index", 
      "End": true 
    } 
  }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine api gateway which is synchronous, with step functions which are asynchronous. If you use step functions your flow should be asynchronous. You will not get the response with a single API call. You will need to create another API which will keep "polling" the step function to see if it has successfully executed and what the response is.

Here is the flow you can try out.

1. API call that initializes the step function. You can try directly connecting the API gateway post call with your step function and see if it returns the execution arn in response. If it does you won't need a lambda. If it doesn't, then stick to your current lambda and make it return execution arn.
2. Your app then gets the execution arn and uses it to call another API periodically. You can either call API periodically or have the lambda in backend keep polling for response if you think the time it takes to complete step function execution will be less than 30 seconds (API gateway timeout limit).
3. Your second API/Lambda then finds the result of execution using [DescribeExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html), and returns the response.

Edit:
*If you believe your step functions will execute consistently under 30 seconds, you can try using a single lambda to start the step function and then keep polling it for completion using DescribeExecution.*

Comment: Not sure why a -1 has been added when this is a valid answer to the problem and is laid out nicely. It is worth noting that there does not seem to be a clear answer to the issue of getting a result of chained lambdas and deliver via API Gateway without some intermediary like you described.